# Azure Devops how to obtain secure variable value in task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I declared connection string on the pipeline variables page as secure but in the pipeline I cannot obtain the value. I have already read related page in docs but it doesn't provide an example when I want to use a value in a task.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

```
The task where I want to get the value you can see below
- task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
        displayName: Deploy to App Service
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'free_subscription(id)'
          appName: 'app-service'
          containers: 'containerregistry.azurecr.io/something:$(tag)'
          **WANT TO USE IT HERE**
          appSettings: 'CONNECTION_STRING=$(CONNECTION_STRING)'
```

$(CONNECTION_STRING) returns empty string

**EDIT**

Updated code but it doesn't work anyway... connection string is still empty in app settings.

```
- stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy to App Service
    jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONNECTION_STRING]$CONNECTION_STRING"
        displayName: 'Set variable'
      - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
        displayName: Deploy to App Service
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'free_subscription(id)'
          appName: 'app-service'
          containers: 'appnamecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/repository:$(tag)'
          appSettings: |
            [
              {
                "name": "CONNECTION_STRING",
                "value": "$(CONNECTION_STRING)",
                "slotSetting": false
              }
            ]
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, how about this issue? Could answers below help to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi. I had really busy last two days so didn't have time to check. Going to create a solution based on your asnwer tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 solutions that work

By variables section ( I prefer that way)

```
 variables:
tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
# Set secret variable to pipeline variable
CONNECTION_STRING_UNSECRET: $(CONNECTION_STRING)

- stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy to App Service
    jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
        displayName: Deploy to App Service
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'free_subscription(id)'
          appName: 'app-service'
          containers: 'appnamecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/repository:$(tag)'
          appSettings: |
        -CONNECTION_STRING $(CONNECTION_STRING_UNSECRET)
```

AND by bash script

```
    - stage: Deploy
            displayName: Deploy to App Service
            jobs:
            - job: Deploy
              displayName: Deploy
              pool:
                vmImage: ubuntu-latest
              steps:
    - bash: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONNECTION_STRING_UNSECRET]$ 
 CONNECTION_STRING_ENV_VARIABLE"
        displayName: 'Set variable'
        env:
          CONNECTION_STRING_ENV_VARIABLE: $(CONNECTION_STRING)
              - task: AzureWebAppContainer   @1
                displayName: Deploy to App Service
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: 'free_subscription(id)'
                  appName: 'app-service'
                  containers: 'appnamecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/repository:$(tag)'
                  appSettings: |
                -CONNECTION_STRING $(CONNECTION_STRING_UNSECRET)
```

**Btw** if you see "***" value of your variable in console it means your step has read the value successfully.

Thanks @Lance Li-MSFT for the links they really helped me.

Comment: Cheers! Glad to know you're resolved the issue and thanks for sharing the solution. Please consider [accepting this own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that members with similar issue can benefit from the marked answer and we can archive this thread for you~

Answer (score 2):

You are overlooking this when selecting a secret Pipeline variable:
[image]

This is [referenced here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables) So depending on if your OS is Linux or Windows it would be:
Linux: `$CONNECTION_STRING`
Windows: `%CONNECTION_STRING%`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did as it is described in your link but it doesn't work anyway :( I updated the question with new code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have already read related page in docs but it doesn't provide an
> example when I want to use a value in a task.

To use variables defined in script as inputs of next step, you can check [Use variables as task inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-variables-as-task-inputs). For more details you can check my [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118034/10910450).

> Connection string is still empty in app settings.

As I know the recommended format of appsettings is `-key value` instead of the json format above.
Sample:

```
          appSettings: |
            -Port 5000 -RequestTimeout 5000 
            -WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE "Eastern Standard Time"
```

Instead of modifying the ConnectionString in AzureWebAppForContainer task, I suggest using [Azure App Service Settings task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops) after your `AzureWebAppContainer` step to configure the ConnectionString. You can use this format in `connectionStrings` input of `AzureAppServiceSettings` to configure what you want:

```
connectionStrings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "MysqlCredentials",
          "value": "$(MySQl_ConnectionString)",
          "type": "MySql",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
```